# how to handle large values in gnuplot

Tags: linux, gnuplot

I have below sample file which has large values more than 10000000.

```
date,value1,value2,value3,value4
2009-06-01,16100834.94,20891965.33,15271434.3,9923084.09
2009-06-02,15061830.06,17072556.28,12578230,10591562.41
2009-06-03,14508669.28,18841097.35,15536549.47,13583187.15
2009-06-04,13771192.1,15689469.39,24404897.6,10371282.63
```

I can plot the graph but in graph the values in Y axis are shown in exponential numbers. i.e.

```
10000000 = 1e+7
```

How can i display the Y range values in decimal numbers only instead of exponential.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use below before plot

```
gnuplot> set format y "10^{%L}"
gnuplot> set terminal postscript eps enhanced 
gnuplot> set ylabel "Y-AXIS" 2,0
```

you will get the values in 10^. For other formats look at this [link](http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/tics-e.html)

Hope this helps.